# Rust cannot infer type without annotation

Tags: types, rust

The code below cannot compile due to the type error `error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve _: std::cmp::Eq`. What type annotation is needed in order to compile this code?

This example code is taken from a much larger program where `MyHashGenerator::hash_node()` is used to hash nodes in an AST (the type `T` relates to a value that is held inside AST nodes, but the definition of the AST is not needed to reproduce the type error).

```
use std::hash::Hash;

pub trait HashGenerator<T: Clone + Eq + Hash + ToString> {
    fn hash(&self, msg: &str) -> u64;  // Hash a string.
    fn hash_node(&self) -> u64;  // Hash an AST node.
}

struct MyHashGenerator {}

impl<T: Clone + Eq + Hash + ToString> HashGenerator<T> for MyHashGenerator {
    fn hash(&self, msg: &str) -> u64 {
        0
    }

    fn hash_node(&self) -> u64 {
        // error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: std::cmp::Eq`
        self.hash("")
    }
}
```

[Code on Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6859b1d018ce301d87c2207f69397b3b&version=nightly)

This question is similar to [the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104236/how-to-resolve-type-annotations-required-cannot-resolve-when-calling-generi), which has not been answered.

Comment: True. But implementing `Eq` for `MyHashGenerator` doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `MyHashGenerator` doesn't take a type argument. So you're making a promise "The *same* type `MyHashGenerator` will suffice as a hash generator and will behave the exact same way regardless of `T`". `self.hash("")` is a call to `hash` on `HashGenerator`, but Rust doesn't necessarily know that it's the *same* `HashGenerator` instance that `hash_node` was called on. You can make this requirement explicit in one of two ways.

**Option 1: Explicit Type Arguments**

By explicitly telling Rust what the arguments are, you can avoid this problem.

```
fn hash_node(&self) -> u64 {
    HashGenerator::<T>::hash(self, "")
}
```

Now it knows to call specifically the `<T>` instance, which will suffice.

**Option 2: Phantom data**

You can parameterize `MyHashGenerator` to have an (unused) `T` parameter.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData

...

struct MyHashGenerator<T> {
    foo: PhantomData<T>
}
```

Then Rust can infer which instance you want based on the type of `self`, so long as you declare your instance as

```
impl<T: Clone + Eq + Hash + ToString> HashGenerator<T> for MyHashGenerator<T> {
    ...
}
```

Then you don't have to change your implementation of `hash_size`.

Personally, I recommend Option 1. It's not as pretty, but it provides the additional API guarantee that things will in fact work the same way regardless of `T`. However, if you think `MyHashGenerator` might use the `T` argument later (or if it does now, and that simply wasn't included in your MCVE), you may consider going with Option 2 to make that dependency more clear.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. The reason I missed it is that in the original code `self.hash` is passed a function call which itself takes an argument which is parameterised on `T`. C'est la vie, I guess!